# login cookie not saving on page refresh

Tags: php, html, cookies, authentication, login-script

I have a very simple login script.

```
<?php
    $username = "######";
    $password = "######";
    $hostname = "######";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("logindashboard", $dbhandle);

    $myusername = $_POST['user'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM logindashboard.login WHERE user='$myusername' and pass='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    mysql_close();

    if($count==1){
        $seconds = 5 + time();
        setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
        header("location:index2.php");
    }else{
        echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
    }
?>
```

When users log in and are taken to my homepage. They log in, however the page is set to refresh after 45 seconds using meta refresh.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"CONTENT="45;URL=index2.php">
```

The only problem with this is, after 45 seconds they appear to be get taken back to the login screen rather than the page they are already on.

This is what I use on the index2.php file at the very top of the page.

```
<?php require_once('../../../.config2.php'); 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])){
        header("location:index.php");
    }
?>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try adding quotes to your cookie name.

Comment: setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);

changed to

setcookie('loggedin', date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds); 

But this has not made a difference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all your problem is that you don't wrap your `loggedin` in apostrophes. the line should be look like this, to set the login cookie correctly

```
setcookie('loggedin', date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
```

now to your script logic. don't use cookies to check if a user is flagged as `loggedin`. i don't know any user/password combination and can bypass your script simple by setting manually a cookie with the name `loggedIn`.

try to use `sessions` to check if a user is loggedIn. `session` data is stored server-side and can't manually edited by the client.

like this

```
// here connect to you db mysql_connect(...
// mysql_select_db(...

$user = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['user'] );
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['pass'] );

//query if user and pw is valid
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logindashboard.login WHERE user='".$user."' and pass='".$pass."'");    

if( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {

    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header('Location: index2.php');
}
```

your `index2.php` would look like this

```
<?php
session_start();
if( ! $_SESSION['loggedIn'] ) {
    // not logged in redirect direct to login page
    header('Location: loginPage.php');
}
```

this is much more safer then using cookies. as you see you don't need a meta tag to redirect users. use the php `header` function to redirect directly users

Comment: Hey, thanks for that.

Are you suggesting I change login.php to:

// mysql check user/pass
if( $valid ) {

    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;

    header('Location: index2.php');
}else{
 echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
 }

and then, in the index2.php use session start instead of cookie?

The refresh is actually because the page does a select on a DATABASE it's a dashboard which I want to refresh every 45 seconds. So I still need the refresh.

Comment: yep you are on the right way -oh okay don't know the need of permanently refresh

Comment: if $value.

Where is $value defined?

Comment: I just seem to be getting incorrect username and pass now:

login.php

 // mysql check user/pass
 if( $valid ) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header('location:index2.php');
 }else{
 echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
 }

index2.php

<?php require_once('../../../.config2.php'); 
session_start();
if( ! $_SESSION['loggedIn'] ) {
    // not logged in redirect direct to login page
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>

Comment: i updated my answere - take a look at the login logic. ``mysql_real_escape_string`` is the proper way to prevent ``sql injections``

Comment: Ok, I think I have no broken it.

Is it because you don't use the same variable names and I have got confused?

http://pastebin.com/yVyjPgtr

Comment: jep ``$query = mysql_query(`` should be ``$result = mysql_query(``

Comment: delete ``stripslashes`` you don't need them because you now use ``mysql_real_escape_string``

Comment: Same result, Does the query need " and '?

("SELECT * FROM logindashboard.login WHERE user='".$user."' and pass='".$pass."'"); 

Should it not be?

('SELECT * FROM logindashboard.login WHERE user="$user" and pass="$pass"');

Comment: When logged in now, it instantly takes you back to index.php rather than index2.php

Comment: <?php require_once('../../../.config2.php'); 
session_start();
if( ! $_SESSION['loggedIn'] ) {
    // not logged in redirect direct to login page
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?> 

I have this on index2.php